# Detect OS type using Perl

Tags: perl, operating-system

I want to use Perl to detect the OS type.

For example:

Let's say I have an installer, in order to know which commands the installer needs to run. I'll have to detect what operating system is installed, for example Linux. Let's say it's Linux. Now which type of Linux?

- Fedora
- Ubuntu
- CentOS
- Debian
- etc.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 6):

The first step is to check the output of the `$^O` variable.

If the output is for example

> linux

you need more processing to detect which distribution is used.

See `perldoc perlvar`.

So far, you can run `lsb_release -a` to see which distribution is used.

If this command is not present, you can test the presence of files like:

```
/etc/debian_version # debian or debian based
/etc/redhat-release # rpm like distro
```

Other files tests examples: *[Detecting Underlying Linux Distro](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11251.html)*

---

Consider [xaxes' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912348/detect-os-type-using-perl/14912448#14912448) too using the `Linux::Distribution` module to check the distribution.

---

If you want to detect the *package manager*, you can try this approach:

```
 if ($^O eq "linux") {
     my $pm;

     do{
         if (-x qx(type -p $_ | tr -d "\n")) {
             $pm = $_;
             last;
         }
     } for qw/apt-get aptitude yum emerge pacman urpmi zypper/;

     print $pm;
 }
```

Comment: It should be `$^O` (capital letter O), not a zero.

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can use Config (it's a core module). This is an example:

```
use Config;
print "$Config{osname}\n";
print "$Config{archname}\n";
```

On my Mac OS X, it prints:

```
darwin
darwin-2level
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), either `$OSNAME` or `$^O` will give you the operating system. This is also equivalent to using `$Config{'osname'}` (see [Config](http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html) for more). A special note for Windows systems:

> In Windows platforms, `$^O` is not very helpful: since it is always *MSWin32* , it doesn't tell the difference between 95/98/ME/NT/2000/XP/CE/.NET. Use `Win32::GetOSName()` or `Win32::GetOSVersion()` (see [Win32](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32) and [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html)) to distinguish between the variants.

In order to get the exact platform for a Linux box, you'll need to use a module like xaxes mentioned in his answer.

Comment: For example in windows, if I did $^O and if it showed up windows, then could I do like if it = MSWin32 then do like Win32::GetOSVersion() ?

Comment: That's correct. Remember to `use Win32` up at the top of the script.

Answer (score 2):

To determine what OS your script is running on, you can use `$^O`:

```
print $^O
```

And [Linux::Distribution](http://search.cpan.org/~chorny/Linux-Distribution-0.21/lib/Linux/Distribution.pm) to check for the distribution:

```
use Linux::Distribution qw(distribution_name distribution_version);

my $linux = Linux::Distribution->new;
if (my $distro = $linux->distribution_name()) {
      my $version = $linux->distribution_version();
      print "you are running $distro, version $version\n";
} else {
      print "distribution unknown\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes, but its great that its linux in that case, but how to get the exact name to know if to use like apt-get or yum or?

Comment: What about checking the list of package manager? foreach $manager (@package_manager) { $check = ` $manager `; } [here check what does $check contains]

Answer (score 1):

This works well on Redhat or CentOS easily adjustable to others...

```
# Test for release file
my $release_file="";
if ( -e "/etc/redhat-release" ) {
  $release_file="/etc/redhat-release";
} elsif ( -e "/etc/centos-release" ) {
  $release_file="/etc/centos-release";
} elsif ( -e "/etc/system-release" ) {
  $release_file="/etc/system-release";
} else {
  print "OS Release file missing, can't determine version information";
  exit;
}

my $OS_NAME=`cat $release_file|cut -d " " -f1`;
my $OS_MAJOR_VERSION=`sed -rn 's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+)\\.[0-9]+.*/\\1/p' $release_file`;
my $OS_MINOR_VERSION=`sed -rn 's/^[^0-9]*[0-9]+.([0-9]+).*/\\1/p' $release_file`;

chomp($OS_NAME);
chomp($OS_MAJOR_VERSION);
chomp($OS_MINOR_VERSION);

print "\nOS Name and Version: ${OS_NAME} ${OS_MAJOR_VERSION}.${OS_MINOR_VERSION}\n\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check file - /etc/os-release:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use feature(say);
use strict;
use warnings;


my %os=();

unless ( open(OS,"cat /etc/os-release|") ){
        say "ErrorOpenPipe OS_release";
        exit;
}

while (<OS>){
        my @os_param = split /=/, $_;
        $os{$os_param[0]}=$os_param[1];
}


my @FH;

say $os{ID};
say $os{VERSION_ID};
```

Use other key if needed:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial

$ cat /etc/os-release 

NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```